# Hard Drive Partitions for SAS Drives

Tags: sas, partition

We have a Dell server with 3 300GB SAS Drives that are combined as a single drive with two partitions. The partition the OS is on is only 12 GB while the remaining space is on the other partition. We need to resize the 12 GB partition to about double that size, but I am unsure on the best way to do so. Dell recommended we use Partition Magic, but I am concerned since this is physically three hard drives even if the computer sees them all together as a single drive. Will Partition Magic work in this situation. Is there some other way to accomplish this goal.

It should also be said that -- unfortunately -- formatting and reinstalling just isnt an option in this instance.

Comment: What OS you are using? What is the filesystem on both partitions? Can you online resize the partitions, with the OS provided tools?

Comment: Feel free to tell us something relevant. What OS? What file system? In what way are the drives "combined as a single drive with two partitions"? The one thing you have told us, that they are SAS drives, is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the 3 drives are attached to a RAID controller of some sort, Partition Magic claims to support RAID and won't know or care if it is 3 drives or 1 drive or 10 drives;

But I would certainly make sure you have good backups before starting, when things go wrong, they go horribly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

LVM could be good answer for your questions. Or some FS such as ZFS. But if you run Windows OS, try to use soft like Partition Magic.

Answer (score 0):

1. Shut down all active services/applications on the server
2. Copy all data off the second partition to a backup location
3. Delete the second partition
4. Use windows Disk Management (if 2008) or GParted LiveCD (older versions) to extend the C:\ partition to the desired size
5. Re-create the second partition
6. Copy all data back to the second partition
7. Start your services and launch your applications

As with any important system, you need to have a solid backup. If you get in trouble with this (or any other suggested process), you're going to need that backup.